# What does 'trust' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

> That evening, Dudley paraded around the living room for
>   the family in his brand-new uniform. Smeltings' boys wore maroon
>   tailcoats, orange knickerbockers, and flat straw hats called boaters.
>   They also carried knobbly sticks, used for hitting each other while
>   the teachers weren't looking. This was supposed to be good training
>   for later life.
>        As he looked at Dudley in his new
>   knickerbockers, Uncle Vernon said gruffly that it was the proudest
>   moment of his life. Aunt Petunia burst into tears and said she
>   couldn't believe it was her Ickle Dudleykins, he looked so handsome
>   and grown-up. Harry didn't ***trust*** himself to speak. He thought
>   two of his ribs might already have cracked from trying not to laugh.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does ***trust*** mean “to commit or consign with trust or confidence" ([dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trust), *trust*.19)?

Comment: It appears that you asked this exact question once before: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/what-does-didnt-trust-himself-to-speak-mean